# IFrame src not understands #

Tags: html, url, iframe

hi i am using # in my querystring in iframe src but it became truncated.

```
<IFRAME src="Test.jsp?name=check#comment"></IFRAME>
```

it gives me name as only 'check' not as 'check#comment'

Comment: On what end do you want to retrieve the parameter? In your jsp on the server side or in a client javascript?

Comment: Does the `#comment` element exist on the resulting page?  I recall one of the older browser versions used to trim non-existent hash targets.

Answer (score 1):

`#` separates the [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html).

If you want to include `#` in your query parameter, you need to properly encode it as `%23`.

Answer (score 0):

Hash tag (everything located after `#` in URL) is never passed to server with request. It does not depend if you click a link, load iframe or do ajax request.

You should encode `#` or change value so it will not contain `#`